# Replace image pixel color based on channel condition in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I have an RGB image, how can I change the pixel color to either white or black based on comparing the red and blue channel values of the same pixel?

```
if r_pixel > g_pixel:
    # make pixel white
else:
    # Make pixel black
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
img = cv2.imread("car.jpg")
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
new = np.subtract(r , g)
```

The output is a strictly white and black image (0 or 255).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `np.where()` to pick `255` or `0` at each pixel depending on the condition:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image
img = cv2.imread('colorwheel.jpg')

# Wherever R>G, make result white, and black elsewhere
res = np.where(img[...,2]>img[...,1], 255, 0).astype(np.uint8)

# ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION FOLLOWS

# Or you could generate a Boolean (True/False) array and multiply by 255 to get the same result
res = ((img[...,2]>img[...,1]) * 255 ).astype(np.uint8)
```

**Input**

[image]

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can slice the required channels first as shown below, then compare both channels and cast the result from boolean to uint8, then squeeze the singleton channel and multiply by 255:

```
r = img[:,:,2:]
g = img[:,:,1:2]
new = 255*np.squeeze(r>g,axis=2).astype('uint8')
```